# Wrong stack trace line number inside foreach block

Tags: c#, for-loop, exception, .net-4.0, stack-trace

I am having trouble understanding stack traces in .net 4. I get different line numbers for identical code running in Console application or web service hosted on IIS 7.5 (both use .net 4).

**Console application:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var test = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
        foreach (var root in test)
        {
            throw new Exception("foobar");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

When inspecting stack trace line number of "e" inside catch block, I get "8", which is what I excepted (the line of *throw new Exception("foobar")*)

**Web service**

```
[WebMethod]
public void Test()
{
    try
    {
        var test = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
        foreach (var root in test)
        {
            throw new Exception("foobar");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

This is where things get weird - when inspecting stack trace line number, I get "7", **which is the start of *foreach* block**. Same happens with classical *for*, but *if* statement for example work OK.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Regarding answer from Machine Learning about misalignment between the ide or the runtime line and the pdb. If I add nonsensical lines before exception and some after, I still get similar behaviour. Example:

```
[WebMethod]
public string Test()
{
    try
    {
        var test = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };

        var a = 1;
        var b = 2;
        var c = 3;

        foreach (var root in test)
        {
            var d = 4;
            var e = 5;
            var f = 6;
            throw new Exception("foobar" + (new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame(0, true)).GetFileLineNumber());
            var g = 7;
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return e.Message + e.StackTrace;
    }
}
```

Here `e.StackTrace` reports line "12" (`foreach` line) and `e.Message` reports line "17" which is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of how exceptions are handled on Windows. Rethrowing the exception thrown within the same method means you lose information about the original exception, because the exceptions are method scoped [1]. Sadly, .NET inherited this limitation, since the only alternative was to implement exceptions without relying on the existing infrastructure.

<strike>If I recall correctly, this is fixed in 64-bit code - make sure your console application runs as 64-bit, and it should work as expected. This is most likely the reason why everything works fine in your test application, but not on your IIS (where the code is most likely running as 32-bit, and possibly with `debug=false`).</strike> **EDIT:** This actually doesn't seem to be the case. While bitness is involved, it most likely has to do with the optimizations the JITters do - a `foreach` on 64-bit reports the exception on the `foreach` line, while replacing the `foreach` with a `using`, `GetEnumerator` etc., or changing the bitness to 32-bit will report the exception on the rethrow.

If you want to avoid this problem in all code, make sure you never rethrow exceptions that were originally thrown in the same method. Extracting the `throw new ...` into a separate method (and ensuring it isn't inlined, which happens automatically when there's a `throw` on the current MS runtime AFAIK) should work fine. Don't forget that a `foreach` also contains an imlicit `using`, i.e. a `finally` clause.

[1] Needless to say, this is a bit of an oversimplification. The underlying  (native) Structured Exception Handling only holds a single exception per stack frame - it can't keep track of both the original throw and the rethrow. You'll find plenty of information on how SEH works with a simple Google search if you're interested to go deeper :)

Comment: There is no rethrowing involved if you check the EDIT part. Its single try/catch block and exception in catch has line number of the for block instead of line inside the loop. On IIS, I'm running in 64bit (Enable 32-bit applications is set to false). However - I tried running it directly from VS as Machine Learning suggested and it works correctly! So looks like it is something IIS related.

Comment: UPDATE - I set Enable 32-bit applications to true and now line numbers are correct!

Comment: @PavleGartner Well, that's interesting. Does your console code also break in 64-bit? Make sure you do *not* attach the debugger - that disables many of the optimizations that might cause the problem.

Comment: Ok changed Console app to 64-bit, and the problem occurs same as with IIS. If I switch back to 32-bit it works ok. So actually its analog to what you wrote but the other way around.

Comment: @PavleGartner Yeah, that's weird. This will take some spec digging - I was pretty sure it was supposed to be the other way around. It might also be caused by an optimization that doesn't happen on the 32-bit JIT - the 64-bit JITter is a lot more aggressive in optimizations. The try-finally that's part of the `foreach` might be to blame for the lost information - when the stack unwinds to the `finally`, the original exception trace information might be overwritten.

Comment: @PavleGartner Going through the 64-bit SEH exception mechanism, it seems that there is only one entry in the exception history table per stack frame. So it seems that while the mechanism changed a lot, the original limitation is still there. In the original mechanism, you replaced the line number with the one on the rethrow. In the 64-bit one, you get the `foreach`'s line instead. Interestingly, if I change the `foreach` to a manual `using` with `GetEnumerator` etc., it reverts back to showing the line of the rethrow. So there might be some special sauce in a foreach specifically :)

Comment: Wow, but that is kind of bad isnt it? Losing important information like that :) I will mark your answer as accepted, any workarounds?

Comment: @PavleGartner It's a bit annoying, yeah. The simplest workaround is to extract the code into separate methods - keep in mind where the "exception boundaries" are, and avoid cases like this where an exception is passed through multiple constrained sections in the same method (the foreach case is a bit more insidious, but now that you know...). In practice, I didn't find this too troublesome - I rarely have a foreach that has more than a few lines. And a scenario where you catch an exception that you've thrown in the same method already smells kind of funny.